# How to load grayscale image dataset to Mobile net model

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mobilenet

I am trying to load a grayscale image dataset(fashion-mnist) to MobileNet model to predict hand written numbers but according to [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l06c01_tensorflow_hub_and_transfer_learning.ipynb#scrollTo=s4YuF5HvpM1W) tutorial only RGB images can be loaded to the model. When I try to feed fashion-mnist samples, it gives me the following error

> Error when checking input: expected keras_layer_13_input to have shape
>   (224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (224, 224, 1)

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably pre-trained MobileNet is not suitable for this task. You have two different problems. Mobilenet is made for Imagenet images which are 224x224 images with 3 color channels, while MNIST dataset is 28x28 images with one color channel. You can repeat the color channel in RGB:

```
# data.shape [70000, 224, 224, 1] -> [70000, 224, 224, 3]
data = np.repeat(data, 3, -1)
```

But before that, you need to resize images. For example, you can use `PIL` for resizing images:

```
from PIL import Image

data = np.array([Image.fromarray(x).resize([224,224]) for x in data])
```

There are some small details here which you should figure out yourself. Such as `dtype` of the images if you have loaded from the dataset as numpy. You may need to convert numpy types to integers with `np.uint8()`.

Comment: The TensorFlow equivalent would be: `tf.tile(data, [1, 1, 1, 3])`.

Comment: I am loading dataset from this code `splits, info = tfds.load('mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True, split = splits)` so that how to apply above solution for this

Comment: How do you resize the images? They are not 224x224 in mnist!

Comment: `hub.KerasLayer(CLASSIFIER_URL, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))` this is how I resize the images

Comment: but that is not going to resize MNIST images. they have 28 x 28 pixels.

Comment: So than what is the best way to do this? Can't we use MobileNet model to predict greyscale images ?

Comment: I tried to add more explanation. In my solution, I used numpy. Perhaps, there are other solutions in tensorflow as well. i.e. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images

Answer (score 1):

Mobilenet v2 needs RGB. You might also be able to use the convert function from PIL.

Try this:

```
from PIL import Image
x= Image.open(input_image).resize((96,96)).convert("RGB")
```

documentation is here: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

Answer (score 0):

try this, `x = np.stack((x,)*3, axis=-1)`. Please refer to this link for more details: https://github.com/malnakli/ML/blob/master/tf_serving_keras_mobilenetv2/main.ipynb